# macOS terminal login user name is a sequence of alphabets&numbers

Tags: macos, authentication, terminal

Every time when you login to the terminal, at the most lefthandsside, you should see your login name with YOUR_NAME@BLABLA $

However, when I am at home, it will be yuminsMBP:~ and every time when I am at university, the login name is a sequence of alphabets,number and special characters. And I can always see, every time I open the terminal, the first line need about 1 second to show up, it seems like terminal try to compute something or are running some process.

I don't understand why, and can not remember what I have done. Maybe it is because I installed anaconda last year? It is too far away, until today my friend said my login looks super weird, I started to think about this problem.

Do you know what I have done to my mac?

## My .bashrc looks like:

#### Add RVM to PATH for scripting. Make sure this is the last PATH variable change.

export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin"

## My .bash_profile looks like:(I only provide things I think weird.)

blabla...

source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"

#### Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*

blablabla....

#### MacPorts Installer addition on 2017-12-03_at_18:01:33: adding an appropriate PATH variable for use with MacPorts.

export PATH="/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:$PATH"

#### Finished adapting your PATH environment variable for use with MacPorts

blablabla...

Best,
Yumin

Answer (score 0):

The most likely cause is that you have something in your bash_profile that is causing the change. To check this open the .bash_profile file in your user home directory. One way of doing this is by opening terminal and running `cat ~/.bash_profile` you might also need to check your .bashrc file if your bash_profile sources it.

Without further information there is no real way tell what your specific issue is.